# complicated SQL subquery

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables:

```
orders
customers
```

I need to get "VIP customers"- meaning customers that ordered at least once a month since they registerd (there is a column `[subscription_date]` on `customers`)

I cant figure it out :(
any ideas?

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(Orders.OrderID), Customers.CustomerID FROM Customers INNER JOIN Orders ON Orders.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID GROUP BY Customers.CustomerID HAVING COUNT(Orders.OrderID) > 0`

Comment: Structure of `orders`? And "once a month" means once per calendar month or no more than one month has elapsed? i.e. if they order on 1st Jan and 28th Feb are they still VIP?

Comment: Please give the names of tables and the relevant columns, as well as some sample data.  Also, it helps if you tell what brand of SQL you are using, because they are all different.  Finally, it is a good idea to try it yourself first, and post the code of what you tried.

Comment: Try to come up with a better title please. "Complicated" - how do you know? You don't know what the answer may be. "SQL" - there are tags already for indicating technologies/languages. "Subquery" - may or may not be the most important aspect of the answer. And, please add which specific database you're using (e.g. MS SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle, etc)

Comment: For further clarification, in addition to what Martin asked, does ordering twice in one month make up for not ordering in one.  In other words if someone has been a customer for six months, and has ordered 30 times, but didn't make an order during the last month, are they still considered VIP?

Comment: Damien - I will keep that in mind next time. I just couldnt think of a proper Title for this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query counts the number of months each customer as ordered in and compares it to the number of months the customer has had a subscription.
Customers that have an equal value in both are your VIP Customers.

```
SELECT T1.CUSTOMERID AS VIP_CUSTOMERS 
FROM   (SELECT Count(*) AS NUM_MONTHS, 
               CUSTOMERID 
        FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT Month(ORDERDATE), 
                                Year(ORDERDATE), 
                                CUSTOMERID 
                FROM   ORDERS 
                GROUP  BY CUSTOMERID)T 
        GROUP  BY CUSTOMERID)T1 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT CUSTOMERID, 
                          Datediff(MONTHS, SUBSCRIPTION_DATE, Getdate()) AS 
                          NUM_MONTHS 
                   FROM   CUSTOMERS)T2 
               ON T1.CUSTOMERID = T2.CUSTOMERID 
                  AND T1.NUM_MONTHS = T2.NUM_MONTHS
```

If you set up some sample data on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), I'll try to re-write the query according to the data.